# How can i merge the range array by around near value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, range

I have range array in PHP which contain no of range, but i want to marge that all possible rang by around near value ..!

Range array like this :

```
$array = array('1.10','21.30','31.40','41.50','81.90');
```

And i want like below after marge :

```
$array = array('1.10','21.50','81.90');
```

I tried to merged, but I wanted to find out the result that I did not have.

```
$dis  = array();
$array = array('1.10','21.30','31.40','41.50','81.90');

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $ex = explode('.',$value);

    if(isset($dis[$ex[1] + 1])){
        $dis[$ex[1] + 1][0] = $ex[0];
    }else if(isset($dis[$ex[0] - 10])){
        $dis[$ex[0] - 10][1] = $ex[1];
    }else $dis[$ex[0]] = $ex;
}

$new_array = array();
foreach($dis as $value){
    $new_array[] = implode('.',$value)
}

//Output : array('1.10','21.50','41.50','81.90')
```

Will there be any easy solution for this ?

Comment: Are you always looking to have 3 elements in the final array?

Comment: @adpro No, it depends on array value, and it will dynamic array value .

Comment: Ok, then I don't know exactly what you're looking for. Is there documentation on how you want them merged?

Comment: This is very easy. If value1 is 21.30 and value2 is 31.40, then it becomes merge 21.40.
Because the last number of value1 is 30 and the first number of value2 is 31

Comment: I still don't understand. You have 5 values in the first array. You take the part before the decimal of the second value and then merge it with the part after the decimal with the 4th value? Why? Can you maybe edit your answer to explain the logic behind the merge. That's the important piece.

Comment: I think it's because you're losing the `31` after you process that item.

Comment: Let me know if the answer below helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yuu... Finally i made this ans and it working fine..!

```
$dis  = array();
$array = array('121.130','101.110','31.40','61.70','1.10','21.30','51.60','81.90','111.120');
sort($array);
foreach($array as $value){
    $ex = explode('.',$value);
    $no = $ex[0] - 1;
    if(isset($dis[$no])){
        $dis[$ex[1]] = array($dis[$no][0],$ex[1]);
        unset($dis[$no]);
    }else $dis[$ex[1]] = $ex;
}
$new_array = array_map(function($v){ return implode('.',$v); }, $dis);
```